# Accessing generic type from a dispatch queue

Tags: swift

I have a generic class A containing the function:

```
func addItem<item:T>->T? {

}
```

I initialize this class with a CellClass. I call addItem from addCell().The following is accepted without problems.

```
func addCell(cell:CellClass, t:A<CellClass>) {
    t.addItem(cell) 
}
```

But this does not work:

```
func addCell(cell:CellClass, t:A<CellClass> {
    dispatch_async(queue, {
       t.addItem(cell)
    })
```

Xcode complains immediately: *"CellClass? is not a subtype of Void"*
Any ideas why? (Note that the queue works properly otherwise)

Comment: `t.addItem` returns `CellClass?`, the block declaration on `dispatch_aync` expects you to return `Void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift does an ["implicit return" from single-line closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), so your code actually is being interpreted as:

```
func addCell(cell:CellClass, t:A<CellClass> {
    dispatch_async(queue, {
       return t.addItem(cell)
    })
}
```

The error is because the closure has a `Void` return type, but `addItem` is returning `CellClass?`. You can fix this by adding a single `return` line afterward to fix the issue:

```
func addCell(cell:CellClass, t:A<CellClass> {
    dispatch_async(queue, {
        t.addItem(cell)
        return
    })
}
```